# Where is this ridge in Charlevoix, Québec?

Tags: identify-this, quebec

I first saw the picture beneath on [Reddit](https://redd.it/9r4olj).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar view from Google Earth. The parking lot in the distance appears to be [Mont-du-Lac-des-Cygnes Visitors Center in Parc national des Grands-Jardins](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Parc+national+des+Grands-Jardins/@47.6690666,-70.6382848,3688m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x4cbf6fdc1777cd35:0x4665e425f3bc01f5!2sCharlevoix+Regional+County+Municipality,+QC,+Canada!3b1!8m2!3d47.6304216!4d-70.6482074!3m4!1s0x4cbf767de24dda3d:0x4b833137bc511aec!8m2!3d47.666211!4d-70.6276971).

[image]